# GSON exception: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm getting a JSON response (list of items) from a .NET WS, so that I want to transform to a List in my Android app. But when using GSON library, I get the following exception:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

JSON response:

```
{
    "d": [
        {
            "Id":1,
            "Name":"Name1",
            "Email":"name1@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "Id":2,
            "Name":"Name2",
            "Email":"name2@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Android GSON code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<User>>(){}.getType();
List<User> users = (List<User>) gson.fromJson(response, listType);
```

As far as I understand, JSON is returning a list of items, and I'm also trying to parse to a list of items, so I don't understand the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your json is an object not a list

Comment: [Many duplicates...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Expected+BEGIN_ARRAY+but+was+BEGIN_OBJECT)

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 but I did use the browser before posting

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is `{ ... }`, so not a list, but `d` is a list.

This is completely untested, but you should do something like this:

```
class Foo {
    List<User> d;
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
Foo foo = gson.fromJson(response, Foo.class);
List<User> users = foo.d;
```

Comment: This way it works ... but I don't understand why the JSON response includes the {...} that makes it an object and not a list.

Comment: This seems to be some kind oft wrapper object created by your service